# Crontab in docker windows container

Tags: python, docker, cron

Can we add crontab job in a docker windows container ?
If we can't what are the alternatives for docker windows container to be executed in every 10 minutes.

Need to run a Python workflow in windows server 2016(no internet connection) in every 10 minutes.

Let me know if there is any other way to achieve this.

Thanks !

Comment: On a linux os I would use the crontab of the host to execute commands in the container. On Windows, maybe you can use the task scheduler? In my experience, the crontab in the container doesn't work very well.

Comment: Maybe implement in python itself? https://pypi.org/project/croniter/

Comment: Do you mean a Windows OS container running a Linux or a *something* container running a Windows ?